# How to retrieve nested output from XCom using taskflow syntax in Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-taskflow

Well, I know this seems to be possible I just don't know how. To begin with, I am using traditional operators (without @task decorator) but I am interested in XComArgs return output format from these operators that can be used in downstream tasks. Below is a sample example

```
task_1 = DummyOperator(
    task_id = 'task_1'
) # returns {"data": {"foo" : [{"cmd": "ls"}]}}


task_2 = BashOperator(
    task_2='task_2',
    cmd=task_1.output['return_value']['data']['foo'][0]['cmd'] # does not give what I need and returns null. 

    #cmd = f"{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids = 'task_1', key='return_value')['data']['foo'][0]['cmd'] }}" Gives what I need
)
```

In this example what is working for me which is pure Jinja templating and the new syntax does not work for me using XComArgs. I have tried changing the argument `render_template_as_native_obj=True` in Dag configuration but does not change anything. I want to use `.output` format which returns `XcomArgs` object and is returning the complete dict but have not been able to use the nested keys like above. Also, have tried converting string to JSON and all those combinations but does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, retrieving nested values from `XComArgs` in a [limitation of the TaskFlow API](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16618).

The TaskFlow API uses `__getitem__` to override the `XCom` key to use. In your example, the key ends up being "cmd" rather than the value of what `cmd` represents in that nested object. You'll have to use the original `ti.xcom_pull()` method until that limitation is addressed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the PR. I'm not alone then who is looking for something similar.