How to access dict stored in XComArg?
I'd like to retrieve value for a specific key from within JSON passed by XComArg to pass it as an argument to another task.
from airflow.decorators import dag, task

@dag(schedule=None)
def multiple_outputs():

    @task(multiple_outputs=True)
    def extract_employee():
        return {
            "employee": {
                "name": "John",
                "surname": "Doe",
                "age": 34 
            }
        }
    
    @task
    def transform_name(name):
        print(name)

    result = extract_employee()
    # transform_name(result["employee"]["name"])
    result >> transform_name("{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='extract_employee')['employee']['name'] }}")
        
multiple_outputs()

Jinja works fine but I'd like to achieve the same effect using XComArg. In the code snippet commented line provides None instead of employee's name to transform task. Is there a way to solve this issue?

in a PythonOperator function you could try this:
xcom_dict = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='extract_employee')
return xcom_dict["employee"]["name"]

I believe a similar question was raised here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75174852/19091756. In summary, there is a current limitation in retrieving nested objects using the TaskFlow API. See corresponding PR - https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16618
Meanwhile, I believe you may consider using the following syntax to follow TaskFlow API if it is acceptable
from airflow.decorators import dag, task


@dag(schedule=None)
def multiple_outputs():

    @task(multiple_outputs=True)
    def extract_employee():
        return {"employee": {"name": "John", "surname": "Doe", "age": 34}}

    @task
    def transform_name(employee: dict[str, str]):
        name = employee.get("name")
        print(name)

    result = extract_employee()
    transform_name(result["employee"])


multiple_outputs()

